# Angular 2 / typescript binding text to <meta property="og"> from component to index.html

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I bind a variable of a component to the index.html
I want pass/bind a var from a component to the index.html specific i want to change the

```
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
```

Comment: You can't. You can use typescript to update the tag like you'd do with JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following way:

```
let ogTitleMeta = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:title"]'); 
ogTitleMeta.content = 'change content here!';
```

Comment: var ogTitleMeta = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:title"]');
        ogTitleMeta.setAttribute('content', 'here new content')

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
    var allMetaElements = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
    for (var i=0; i<allMetaElements.length; i++) {
        if (allMetaElements[i].getAttribute("property") == "og:title") {
            allMetaElements[i].setAttribute('content', 'change content here!');
        }
    }
```